# cronでembulkを実行すると処理が途中で止まる。

Tags: shellscript, cron, embulk

cronでembulkを実行したいのですが、
cronで設定しているプログラムのキックまではlog確認できるのですが、

処理をログに標準出力して、コマンド実行時とcron時を比べると、cron時だけ処理が止まってしまっています。
エラー内容は以下のようなものです。

```
org.embulk.exec.PartialExecutionException: org.embulk.config.ConfigException: Failed to map a JSON value into some object.
```

ログで見る限りcronで実行したembulk実行は以下の処理で止まっています。

```
2021-11-16 14:00:02.447 +0900: Embulk v0.9.23
2021-11-16 14:00:14.483 +0900 [WARN] (main): DEPRECATION: JRuby org.jruby.embed.ScriptingContainer is directly injected.
2021-11-16 14:00:56.884 +0900 [INFO] (main): Gem's home and path are set by default: "/root/.embulk/lib/gems"
2021-11-16 14:01:26.054 +0900 [INFO] (main): Started Embulk v0.9.23
2021-11-16 14:01:26.197 +0900 [INFO] (0001:transaction): Loaded plugin embulk-input-mysql 
2021-11-16 14:01:27.685 +0900 [INFO] (0001:transaction): Loaded plugin embulk-output-mysql
2021-11-16 14:01:30.755 +0900 [WARN] (0001:transaction): "UTC" is recognized as "Z" to be compatible with the legacy style.
```

通常、CLIからコマンドを叩けば[WARN]の所で止まることはありません。
どのような対策を行えばcronで処理を継続させることが出来るでしょうか？

Answer (score 0):

解決済み。

原因は標準出力のみ抽出していて原因が解らなかっただけです。
標準エラー出力を確認し、バグ修正しました。